# Use variables in Javascript before the data is fetched from an API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, async-await, fetch

There is this piece of javascript-code (which comes from the amazing CodingTrain series!!):

My Question is the following:

We are passing the data-object to the fetch-Post request in line 28. The two variables latand lon were first declared, however not initialized, in line 17. Then they were used to build the data-object in line 20 which is eventually passed into the fetch-function in line 28.

What I do not understand is how these two variables can hold the values of the geolocation already up there in the code. Because the geolocation we are obtaining only below in the lines 35-40. Probably this has to do with how the async and await logic works, but I am not sure.

```
01: <!DOCTYPE html>
02: <html lang="en">
03:   <head>
04:     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
05:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
06:     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
07:     <title>Document</title>
08:   </head>
09:   <body>
10:     <h1>Data Selfie App</h1>
11:     <p>
12:       latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>&deg;<br />
13:       longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>&deg;
14:     </p>
15:     <button id="submit">submit</button>
16:     <script>
17:       let lat, lon;
18:       const button = document.getElementById('submit');
19:       button.addEventListener('click', async event => {
20:         const data = { lat, lon };
21:         const options = {
22:           method: 'POST',
23:           headers: {
24:             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
25:           },
26:           body: JSON.stringify(data)
27:         };
28:         const response = await fetch('/api', options);
29:         const json = await response.json();
30:         console.log(json);
31:       });
32: 
33:       if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
34:         console.log('geolocation available');
35:         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async position => {
36:           lat = position.coords.latitude;
37:           lon = position.coords.longitude;
38:           document.getElementById('latitude').textContent = lat;
39:           document.getElementById('longitude').textContent = lon;
40:         });
41:       } else {
42:         console.log('geolocation not available');
43:       }
44:     </script>
45:   </body>
46: </html>
```

The link to the github repo is this: https://github.com/CodingTrain/Intro-to-Data-APIs-JS

Comment: Line 20 doesn't run until you click on the button. We're assuming that the API will return the data and assign the variables before the user clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code between 19 and 31:

```
button.addEventListener('click', async event => {
    // ...
});
```

... attaches a callback to an event. That callback will not execute *now*. It is code that will execute in some future, namely when the user clicks the button.

You might *move* this block of code to line 44, and it wouldn't change any thing to the logic of the code.

You can see the principle in this simplified code -- with one button (click it):

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let i = 0;

button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("i =", i);
});

i = 10; // This executes first!
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I know it was an easy question. I am coming from a completely different background so I'm having sometimes quite some difficulties grasping JavaScript. So I really appreciate it:)!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't their tutorial explain about variables and variable scoping?

Basically when you have code like this:

```
let someVar;
function a() {}
const someFunc = () => someVar;
// ...
```

Because `a` (and `someFunc`) got defined while they have access to `someVar`, they now keep permanent access to that variable.

In your case, all function declarations below `let lat, lon;` can read and write to those variables at any time. The `getCurrentPosition` will *eventually* write values to those variables, which will then be there for the `'click'` listener to use. If you succeed in pressing the button fast enough, before `getCurrentPosition` finishes *(or if `navigator` isn't available)*, `lat`/`lon` would still be `undefined`.

Another example:

```js
const funcs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs.push(() => i);
}
console.log(funcs.map(f => f()));
```

Inside the loop I create 3 functions (for `i` being `0`, `1` and then `2`). Then later on I call them. Even though `i`'s scope (the `for`-loop's body) is over and the variable is "dead", the functions can still access them because they got declared when the variable was still alive and accessible to them. Also note how each function has access to *just* the `i` variable that was alive when they got declared, not the `i` from an earlier/later iteration.

Comment: thanks a lot! I think I get it every time a little more:)